# Plot 3 * 4 matrix with each cell representing one data point

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, heatmap

My data consists of 51 patients who belong to different groups in two test batteries. I would like to plot a matrix with 51 data points. It has to be a 3*4 matrix. I want a plot which basically tells me which data point (in this case a patient) belongs to which two groups of the two test batteries. If there is an agreement or difference in the classifications in two settings (i.e., x axis and y axis). I want the plot to have a distinct cell for each patient so I can visualise which patient belongs to which two groups. My baseline code is this

```
long_data<-melt(data)
x=long_data$Limited
y=long_data$Extensive 
ggplot(data_long, 
aes(x = x, y = y,fill=Factor))
+geom_tile()+
geom_text(aes(label=number))+
labs(x='Limited test battery',
y='Extensive test battery')
```

With this code I am getting something like this:
[image: plot screenshot]

but I would like the plot to represent each data point/cell (now it's clustered and there is overlap).

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How to put 51 data points in a 3*4 matrix, which has 12 cells? If you only have 2 groups the matrix can be e.g. 2 columns / 51 rows.

Comment: I agree. What kind of plot would you suggest for this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to use `ggplot2` and `geom_point`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(grp, patid, col=grp)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 45)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=1/10)
```

[image: point plot]

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(patid = 1:51, grp = c("Agreement", "Agreement", 
"Agreement", "Agreement", "Difference", "Difference", "Difference", 
"Difference", "Agreement", "Difference", "Agreement", "Difference", 
"Agreement", "Difference", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Difference", 
"Difference", "Difference", "Difference", "Agreement", "Agreement", 
"Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Difference", "Agreement", 
"Agreement", "Agreement", "Agreement", "Difference", "Difference", 
"Difference", "Difference", "Agreement", "Difference", "Agreement", 
"Difference", "Difference", "Difference", "Agreement", "Agreement", 
"Difference", "Difference", "Difference", "Difference", "Difference", 
"Difference", "Difference", "Agreement", "Difference")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -51L))
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I would like a plot that resembles a matrix with each of my data points. I would like to visualise which groups they belong to (like my previous plot) and if there is an agreement or disagreement. I can give you a little bit of background to my study if that would be make it easier to understand.